# Python: "[Errno 2] No such file or directory" with file in directory

Tags: python, operating-system

I want to iterate through a directory and read some files.
The working directory is set correctly. I printed the dirname and filename and it should work. But it doesn't.

Could you please help me?

My code is:

```
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    for fname in fileList:
        if fname.endswith(res):
            print (dirName)
            print (fname)
            with open(fname) as file:
                for line in file:
                    ....
```

And the output and error is:

```
.\86

output086.csv_cat1.res

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-59-9583577f0a41> in < module >()

     38             print (dirName)
     39             print (fname)
     40             with open(fname) as file:
     41                 for line in file:
     42                     x = re.match(regex_x, line)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'output086.csv_cat1.res'
```

Problem seems to be line 40.

Comment: Just to confirm, the file you are trying to access is called "output086.csv_cat1.res" and not "csv_cat1.res" right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fname` is just a filename, not an absolute path to the file you are trying to open.  You need to join it with the absolute path of the directory it is in:

`import os
with open(os.path.join(dirName, fname)) as fh:
   ...`

Also, don't use `file` as a variable name because it's a builtin in python.